# How does Trusteer Rapport install itself in all my browsers?

Tags: security, browser, browser-addons

Like so many people, I am forced to install Trusteer Rapport to use the online platform of my bank. I ran the installer and now Trusteer Rapport is installed in all my browsers: Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome.

How does it do this? I never had to agree with anything and find it strange/alarming that this can happen with Firefox and Chrome.

Does anyone know of a way to have this installed only in one browser (IE in my case)?

Comment: The act of you installing was the agreement.  Take a look at their website.  I would place money on the fact there is a single installer which advertises it supports all of the major browsers.

Comment: That is me as a person agreeing. But I find it strange that Firefox/Chrome would "allow" such a thing. When you normally install a plugin/extension, you need to specifically click a button, in the browser.

Comment: You can install Flash in both browsers through an installer and in both cases the extension would be installed without a prompt.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to assume 1 of 2 scenarios and the a few solutions that fix both:

Scenario 1)

You have no option to manually install (from bank enrollment site)

See if its possible to manually download it and install VIA Custom Install and uncheck/ disapprove install to undesired browsers.

Scenario 2)

You use the "Express Install"  in which auto assume and auto install (often also infect)

Choose  Custom Install and follow Fix in Scenario 1...

If either option is not available OR as a catch all  go into  all affected browsers in the toolbars/extensions/certificates sections and remove /lower trust levels

**some may not allow you to remove --in this case you should still be able to select trust level  for certain actions  uncheck as much as is possible)